# How to move whole body into an IFRAME? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

for testing purposes, I want to move the whole body into an `<iframe>`. I did this:

```
$('<iframe width="300" height="600" id="someId"></iframe>').appendTo('body');
$('#someId').contents().find('body').append ($('body').html());
```

but has no effect.

Comment: funny, you want to put IFRAME inside of itself...

Comment: Works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/bffh8/
Mind you, this way you're appending the body WITH the newly added iframe to the iframe, some browsers might not deal well with that! Better solution: "Backup" the HTML before adding the iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/bffh8/1/

Comment: ok :) remove the "alert" and it immediatly stops working :)

Comment: another thing, if you move whole page, the CSS are missing....

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

`$('<iframe width="300" height="600" id="someId"></iframe>').append($('body').html());`